ngOnInit in an Angular reactive form
I am building a form with Angular reactive forms and i want to set a form control value with a property from a service, but when i submit the form, the form control value is not what I expected (the property value from the service) but the value from the component.
mycomponent.ts:
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.date = this.calendarService.date;
    }

  public date:string = "test";

  public payForm: FormGroup = this.formbuilder.group({
    date: [this.date, [], []],
  })

mycomponent.html
<form id="payform" [formGroup]="payForm" >
  <input matInput [value]="date">
</form>

I am confused about how the component lifecycle works here, because the form is created i can see the value from the service in the screen.
Can you help me to understand how to send the value correctly? thank you

When you use ReactiveForms, not use [value], you use [formControl]="control" (if "control is a formControl) or formControlName="name" if you have a formGroup defined and have a property "name" that it's a formControl.

https://angular.dev/guide/components/lifecycle

you need to declare the date and the form outside the onInit and then initialize the for in the OnInite method
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public date: string = "test";
  public payForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private calendarService: CalendarService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.date = this.calendarService.date;

    this.payForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      date: [this.date, [], []]
    });
  }
}

make a onSubmit method to get the form value
<form id="payform" [formGroup]="payForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input matInput formControlName="date">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

